# Batch creation in exchange rest call

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, recurrence, outlook-restapi

I  am performing multiple create operation using batch rest call in exchange.

Will the response be available in the same ordered of the batch request or will it be unordered???

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will be in the same order as the request.

The following snippet from the OData protocol:

> Structurally, a batch response body MUST match one-to-one with the corresponding batch request body, such that the same multipart MIME message structure defined for requests is used for responses.